# Using unique records as table header

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have these 3 tables

1. Student table `[student_id(pk), firstname, lastname]`
2. Subject table `[subject_id(pk), subject_title]`
3. Grade table `[score_id(pk), score, student_id(fk), subject_id(fk)]`

**Is there a way that I can come up with a query such that I can display it to a table in this form:**

_______________________________________
| Student Name | Subject 1 | Subject 2 | Subject 3 |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|__student1___|___98____|___92___|___97___|
|__student2___|___93____|___91___|___95___|
|__student3___|___95____|___92___|___97___|
|__student4___|___97____|___95___|___91___|

Student names come from Student table 
Subject 1, Subject 2, Subject comes from unique records of Subject table
and then
the grades from Grade table

Is it possible or is my database schema design bad?

Here's the table records

```
Student table
|student_id | student_name|
|     1     |   student1  |
|     2     |   student2  |
```

```
Subject table
|subject_id | subject_name|
|     1     |   subject1  |
|     2     |   subject2  |
|     3     |   subject3  |
```

```
Grade table
| grade_id | grade | subject_id | student_id |
|     1    |   87  |     1      |     1      |
|     2    |   87  |     2      |     1      |
|     3    |   87  |     3      |     1      |
|     4    |   87  |     1      |     2      |
|     5    |   87  |     2      |     2      |
|     6    |   87  |     3      |     2      |
```

Comment: Can you provide the *input* data that would result in that particular output?

Comment: did you mean the records from each table?

Comment: Your table design is good. The result you're looking for is called a `PIVOT`. Typically the responsibility of your Reporting Layer, but quite possible in SQL. - alternatively, it can be created with a number of JOINs.

Comment: @JLineses . . . Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: hi, @MarkD can you give some directions to get me started. i'm quite new on sql queries.

Comment: Will provide 1 way of doing it shortly

Comment: Sure, I'll give you directions.  Specify your database software.  SQL is an acronym standing for Structured Query Language.  Lot's of database engines use SQL but the method of achieving certain things is not the same for each database engine.  What you are attempting is one of those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic SQL approach is to use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.studentName,
       max(case when s.subjectName = 'subject1' then g.grade end) as Subject1,
       max(case when s.subjectName = 'subject2' then g.grade end) as Subject2,
       max(case when s.subjectName = 'subject3' then g.grade end) as Subject3
from (students s join
      grades g
      on s.student_id = g.student_id
     ) join
     subjects su
     on g.subject_id = su.subject_id
group by s.studentid, s.studentName;
```

Several databases also support the `pivot` syntax to do this.

EDIT:

The Access query is:

```
select s.studentName,
       max(iif(s.subjectName = 'subject1', grade,  NULL)) as Subject1,
       max(iif(s.subjectName = 'subject2', grade,  NULL)) as Subject2,
       max(iif(s.subjectName = 'subject3', grade,  NULL)) as Subject3
from students s inner join
     grades g
     on s.student_id = g.student_id inner join
     subjects su
     on g.subject_id = su.subject_id
group by s.studentid, s.studentName;
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that i was using MS Access. I've altered some statements from your answer to get it to work. thanks. 
Here are the changes i made: 1. used IIF instead of case statement 
2. enclose in a parenthesis the joining of tables in the FROM clause.

Comment: @JLineses . . . It is important to mention the database engine in the question.  I updated the answer with the Access version.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are only ever going to have 3 subjects, this is the easiest way to do it.

```
;WITH Student(student_id, student_name) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'student1'    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'student2' 
)
,[Subject] (subject_id, subject_name) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'subject1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'subject2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'subject3'
)
,Grade (grade_id, grade, subject_id, student_id) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 87, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 87, 2, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 87, 3, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 87, 1, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 87, 2, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 87, 3, 2 
)
SELECT   S.student_name
        ,Subject1   = G1.grade
        ,Subject2   = G2.grade
        ,Subject3   = G3.grade
FROM Student    S
JOIN Grade      G1  ON S.student_id = G1.student_id AND G1.subject_id = 1
JOIN Grade      G2  ON S.student_id = G2.student_id AND G2.subject_id = 2
JOIN Grade      G3  ON S.student_id = G3.student_id AND G3.subject_id = 3
```

PIVOT method;

```
;WITH Student(student_id, student_name) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'student1'    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2, 'student2' 
)
,[Subject] (subject_id, subject_name) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 'subject1' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'subject2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 'subject3'
)
,Grade (grade_id, grade, subject_id, student_id) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 87, 1, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 87, 2, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 87, 3, 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 87, 1, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 87, 2, 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6, 87, 3, 2 
)
,PrePivot AS 
(
    SELECT   S.student_name
            ,ST.subject_name
            ,G.Grade
    FROM Student    S
    JOIN Grade      G   ON S.student_id = G.student_id
    JOIN [Subject]  ST  ON G.subject_id = ST.subject_id
)
SELECT *
FROM PrePivot
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Grade)
    FOR subject_name IN (subject1, subject2, subject3)
)PVT
```